# How to change asp.net core view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I´m currently trying to change the view by clicking an button.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(int id, [Bind("selectedTraining, selectedTimeZone, selectedLocation")] InstallTraining newTraining)
{ 

    var viewDataDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary<InstallTraining>(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
    {
        Model = newTraining
    };


    var viewResult = new ViewResult();
    viewResult.ViewName = "InstallTraining";
    viewResult.ViewData = viewDataDictionary;

    ViewData["InstallTraining"] = newTraining;
    ViewData["selectedLocation"] = newTraining.selectedLocation;

    this.ViewData["InstallTraining"] = newTraining;
    this.ViewData["selectedLocation"] = newTraining.selectedLocation;


    return viewResult;
}
```

However when I reach the new view I always get the error message that the object reference is not set to an object:

[image: Error Message]

I'm not quite sure why this happens. 
The view that should be shown is quite simple. When I remove the

```
   <div>@Model.selectedLocation</div>
```

it's shown but as soon as I add it I get this error.

I tried using

```
return View("InstallTraining", newTraining);
```

But I get an error that View is not known.

Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong? The OnPost function is embedded in my first view that should trigger the second one.

Comment: The error is telling you that `selectedLocation` is null... and I cannot see were you are actually populating it...

Comment: Do you use correct `@model` directive?What is error using return View()?

Comment: Ah thanks...I needed to change @model to @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.selectedTraining)

Answer (score 0):

@model didn´t work in my code. 
I changed it to

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.selectedTraining)
```

an the code works as expected